# How to define the date format?

Tags: java, date-format

I have the `int` number 2455449 and I know that represents the date 09/09/2010. How can I define the date format wihch is used?  I need to generate a new date in this format. It will be used for http requests. I suppose that is Julian but  I'm  not  sure.  I tried to convert this number to the date but it didn't return the right date of 09/09/2010.  Probably I used a wrong `SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy")` or Calendar.XXXX (e.g.`Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR`)

Comment: Where did you get 2455449 and how did it convert to 09/09/2010?

Comment: I analysed the http requests to the server. I filled  the calendar date in 09/09/2010 and got this number (2455449) in http  request to the server.

Comment: Can you show the code that you used?

Comment: It's the Julian day. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Converting_Gregorian_calendar_date_to_Julian_Day_Number Number of days since January 1, 4713 B.C,in the Julian calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [Julian day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) number, and it counts the number of days since January 1, 4713 BC Greenwich noon in the Julian proleptic calendar.

To convert from a JD to a unix time stamp:

```
unix_time_stamp = ( JD -2440587.5) * 86400
```

To convert from unix time stamp to JD:

```
JD = (unix_time_stamp / 86400) + 2440587.5
```

Note that JD is counted from the noon, not midnight. That's why it's .5 at the end of the addition.

**Update** If you want to use it in javascript (that uses milliseconds since the epoch)

```
function dateFromJulianDay(julian_day) {
  return new Date( (julian_day - 2440587.5) * 86400000);
}

function dateToJulianDay(date) {
  // date should be a javascript Date object
  // or a variable with milliseconds since the unix epoch 1 jan 1970
  return ( date / 86400000) + 2440587.5;
}

console.log(dateFromJulianDay(2455449));

console.log(dateToJulianDay(new Date(2010,9-1,9)));
```

Remember that the month in the Date constructor is 0-11, whats why I do -1 above.

Comment: Many thanks! I have found a better solution for me  - http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0506.html

Comment: @user341203: Is this question wrongly marked as javascript? Are you using dates from different centuries? The code that you link to looks very complicated compared to one-lines like `Calendar.setTimeInMillis((julian_day - 2440587.5) * 86400000)` and `(Calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 86400000) + 2440587.5` (I haven't tested this java code, but you get the idea). I'm just curious! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var now = new Date();

now.format("m/dd/yy");
// Returns, e.g., 6/09/07

// Can also be used as a standalone function
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
// Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM

// You can use one of several named masks
now.format("isoDateTime");
// 2007-06-09T17:46:21

// ...Or add your own
dateFormat.masks.hammerTime = 'HH:MM! "Can\'t touch this!"';
now.format("hammerTime");
// 17:46! Can't touch this!
```

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 1):

looks like an equation with unknown function.

```
f(d,m,y)=D;
```

Where d the day, m month,y year and D is int date. And without loss of generality we can assume that this mapping should be one to one i.e. every valid (d,m,y) combination should map to a unique positive integer (>=0) and every positive integer must represent a valid and unique (d,m,y) tuple.
So the most obvious choice of function f (based on the property of dates) is number of days elapsed since the first day, which satisfies our conditions. so now we have boundary condition.

```
f(d1,m1,y1)=0;
f(9,9,2010)= 2455449;
```

where d1,m1,y1 represents the reference date like epoch in unix timestamp. Using the obvious function (see above), (d1,m1,y1) comes out to be (10 5 -4713). So the DatFormat used is **number of days elapsed since 10th June 4713 B.C.** Approximately.

Comment: Formal win ;-) Would be nice to validate your results with another sampling point - user341203, could you enter another date and tell us the result?

Comment: I think it should be January 1, 4713 B.C, the epoch of the Julian day: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Converting_Gregorian_calendar_date_to_Julian_Day_Number